# mybatis column extraction with out using user defined object in resultmap

Tags: object, mapping, mybatis

i have to execute some query and this query returns only one record with three columns always.

i am using mybatis. i am trying to avoid creating separate class to Map these column values . Is there any way we can extract these column values ??

Thanks in advance for solution

Comment: Have you considered returning List<Map<String,Object>> ?

Comment: can you please share with example

Comment: Give me an example to show you one?

Comment: I have a table A. and when executed it return single row

example :

Table A:

 1      |   2  |   3   |
 ab  |  cd  |    ef
 here 1, 2,3 are column names and ab,cd,ef are column values.
 now I don't want to create object to map values as it always returns singe row . I want these three column values as list<string> or any format that can be convertable to Java

Comment: May I know the database which you are using?

Comment: DB2 Database  and i have to execute query using mybatis